# Database Encryption - Javascript Decryption

Tags: javascript, sql-server, encryption

I will be storing user passwords in a SQL Server database that I would like to keep encrypted. In another application that runs scripts written in javascript, I would like to retrieve this encrypted string from the database and decrypt the string and use the value.

What are the possibilities of doing such a workflow? Can I make use of PGP from both ends? I've heard that in general javascript should be avoided for various security reasons, but in current situation this is not a problem.

Comment: Don't store the passwords encrypted; hash them. This way, there's no way to get the value, but you can compare something to it. I can't imagine why you'd need the decrypted values

Comment: i have to point out that most common hashes like md5 can be broken in realtime using rainbow tables on consumer hardware... Common distributions go up to 13 chars, and most users use shorter ones.

Comment: Though (unsurprising to anyone with any crypto experience at all), there's still lots of things that can be done wrong when hashing.

Comment: The passwords are part of my client's SFTP credentials. So I would like to store these (preferably encrypted) in the database, then in the other application be able to decrypt and use the password to log into that client's SFTP account.

Comment: The reason we don't store passwords in clear is only to protect against an attacker that would somehow gain access to the server. Under this threat model, the attacker will have access to your encryption key.

Comment: So do you have any other recommendations about how to go about the scenario that I'm in?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this myself. The solution I went with is in .NET to encrypt the string using AES, then decrypt using the CryptoJS library in javascript.

Very good example of the .NET ecnryption: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/AES-Encryption-Decryption-Cryptography-Tutorial-with-example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Then store I just the encrypted string as is in the database. When I needed to use the password in the other application that uses javascript as it's scripting engine, I used CryptoJS for my decrypting needs.

Took a second to get them to work together, but once the kinks were worked it's been a pretty good solution for what I was trying to do.